# RuntimeError: addmm(): argument 'mat1' (position 1) must be Variable, not torch.FloatTensor

Tags: python, variables, pytorch, tensor

I am running this extremely simple PyTorch example NN from [the documentation](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/examples_nn/two_layer_net_nn.html#sphx-glr-beginner-examples-nn-two-layer-net-nn-py) as is, with nothing at all changed.

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/opt/conda/envs/fastai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 357, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/fastai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py", line 67, in forward
    input = module(input)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/fastai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 357, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/fastai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py", line 55, in forward
    return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/fastai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 835, in linear
    return torch.addmm(bias, input, weight.t())
RuntimeError: addmm(): argument 'mat1' (position 1) must be Variable, not torch.FloatTensor
```

Apparently during the matrix multiplication, there is some data type error.
Why would the matrices I'm trying to multiply need to be Variable anyway?

I can do
`x = Variable(torch.randn(N, D_in)) 
y = Variable(torch.randn(N, D_out))`
but get
`AttributeError: 'Variable' object has no attribute 'item'`
so that didn't help.

I am running PyTorch version 0.3.1.post2.

Answer (score 3):

I think I just found the answer to my own question, so I'll leave this here if anyone else comes across this:

`**NOTE:** These examples have been update for PyTorch 0.4, which made several major changes to the core PyTorch API. Most notably, prior to 0.4 Tensors had to be wrapped in Variable objects to use autograd; this functionality has now been added directly to Tensors, and Variables are now deprecated.`

So this means I'm running and old version of PyTorch

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, so I will just add the update commands in case you don't want to search them:
Optional:

```
conda list | grep pytorch 
conda upgrade conda
```

The following update didn't update anything, although they should and I think its the right way to update (you may try it first)

```
conda update pytorch torchvision
```

What did help was to specify the version explicitly:

```
conda install pytorch=0.4.0 -c pytorch
```